# Base class has incomplete type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class `Point` from which I inherit in `Point3D`.  However, for some reason class `Point` must always return `Point3D` for the operation `add`, so I include it in my includes.

This is my class `Point`:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include "Point3D.hpp"

class Point{

  public:
    Point(double, double, double);

    void print() const;
    Point3D add( const Point& );

  protected:
    double mX;
    double mY;
    double mZ;

};

#endif
```

In my class `Point3D`, I know I will not yet have encountered the definition of `Point` when I will first be called (because `Point3D` is included in the `Point` header), so I define `class Point;`, then I define the parts I will use of `Point`:

```
#ifndef POINT3D_H
#define POINT3D_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Point.hpp"  // leads to the same error if ommitted

class Point;    

class Point3D : public Point {

  public:
        Point3D(double, double, double);
        void print() const ;
        Point3D add(const Point&);
};

#endif
```

However, this is not working.  When I compile it, it gives me the following error:

```
./tmp/Point3D.hpp:9:24: error: base class has incomplete type
class Point3D : public Point {
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~
./tmp/Point3D.hpp:7:7: note: forward declaration of 'Point'
class Point;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680287/base-class-has-incomplete-type-error) would say to remove the include `#include "Point.hpp"` from my `Point3D` declaration.  However, doing so leads to the same result, and I think the header-guards would basically accomplish the same thing.

I'm compiling with clang.

Comment: You've a circular dependency between Point and Point3D.  Point should likely only operate on Point types, and then Point3D should add, overload/hide members that are specific.

Comment: Absolutely, however this is part of an assignment I'm doing at school and the prof specifically asked this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't inherit from an incomplete type. You need to structure your code as follows:

```
class Point3D;

class Point
{
    // ...
    Point3D add(const Point &);
    // ...
};

class Point3D: public Point
{
    // ...
};

Point3D Point::add(const Point &)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Function return types may be incomplete, which is why your class definition of `Point` works like this.

I trust you can figure out how to split that across header and source files. (For example, the first two parts can go in `Point.hpp`, the third in `Point3D.hpp` which includes `Point.hpp`, and the final implementation can go in `Point.cpp` which includes `Point.hpp` and `Point3D.hpp`.)

Comment: Thanks, that was just it!  I also understood what my error was.